# iPod shows more tracks than Library after sync with Banshee

Tags: 11.10, banshee, sync, ipod

I am running Ubuntu 11.10, Gnome Shell 3.2 and Banshee 2.2.

Banshee correctly recognizes my 80GB iPod Classic (Model No MB147LLm, Version 1.1.2 PC). I have set Banshee to sync the entire library for the iPod.

When I sync, the iPod shows more music tracks than the Banshee library. The difference is large - some 5,500 Banshee tracks and about 5,900 tracks on the iPod.

What is happening? What is the remedy?

Comment: What type of iPod are you syncing and what version of iOS is it running?

Comment: Its an iPod classic 80gb. Model No MB147LL and Version 1.1.2 PC. I got this all from iPod settings menu.

Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Install [gtkpod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gtkpod.1.html).

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```

You can also copy the existing contents of your iPod in their original name unlike some system generated alphabets of iTunes.

Comment: This could be a solution. But it does not solve my problem with Banshee :)

Also, will it transfer my playlists/ ratings from Banshee?